# Ruby on Rails finding the number of items in a cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have my Rails models in an online store I making setup with a cart that has line items. Every time a product is clicked on, a line item is generated that has a unique cart id, matching carts I make for user sessions (this example comes from the book Agile Web Development with rails.)

I want to count the number of items in a users cart, what's the best way to do this.

here's an example of what

```
li.each do |line|
     puts li.to_yaml
end
```

outputs ....

```
- !ruby/object:LineItem
  attributes:
    id: 14
    product_id: 81
    cart_id: 11
    created_at: 2012-06-27 14:10:09.060706000Z
    updated_at: 2012-06-27 14:10:09.060706000Z
    quantity: 1
---
- !ruby/object:LineItem
  attributes:
    id: 1
    product_id: 2
    cart_id: 6
    created_at: 2012-06-25 18:29:20.726280000Z
    updated_at: 2012-06-25 18:56:08.690670000Z
    quantity: 2
- !ruby/object:LineItem
  attributes:
    id: 2
    product_id: 4
    cart_id: 6
    created_at: 2012-06-25 18:56:10.014333000Z
    updated_at: 2012-06-25 18:56:10.014333000Z
    quantity: 1
```

So, I'd want the user with cart_id of 6 to know they have 3 items.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a better way. How are your models set up? Basically you'd want users to have a cart and a cart belongs_to a user. Also, since a line_item has a cart_id, you can have line_item belongs_to cart and cart has_many line_items.

With these associations, you can easily get what you need like:

```
cart.line_items.count

user.cart

user.cart.line_items
```

etc.

You can read up on rails associations here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using the console

After choosing a cart so that `@cart.id = 6` (`current_cart = Cart.find(6)` since the console didn't set the cart using a browser session)

```
@count = 0

LineItem.all.each do |item|
     if (item.cart_id == @cart.id)
       @count += item.quantity
     end
end
```

There must be a better, more railsy way, though...

Comment: If you've set up your associations like I said below, you don't need to query all line_items just to check how many of them are in a cart

Answer (score 0):

```
current_cart.line_items.size
```

Provided you have the following in cart.rb

```
  has_many :line_items
```

-edit-

Ops, sorry, you wanted the sum of quantity.

```
current_cart.line_items.sum('quantity')
```